# Can't get Backbone routes without hashes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I want to have bookmarkable URLs that the browser can capture and handle. If I just use ***Backbone.history.start()***, then I can use hash URLs, like ***/#accounts***.

But I want URLs without the hashes, a la ***/accounts***. But I can't get this to work using ***Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true } )*** ([as others have described it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310230/backbone-routes-without-hashes)). My routes are straightforward, and taken directly from [the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router).

```
    MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '/accounts': 'accounts',
        }
    });
```

I'm using Chrome (also tried with FF), and the behaviour is that an ***/accounts*** request goes straight to the server. Not being intercepted by Backbone first. Has anyone run into this? How do I get
 hash-less URL handling with Backbone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The # is used for internal linking in html, all urls without # will go to server. You can still add routes, but all links with out # will go by server first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would navigate to that url with js using `router.navigate( "/accounts", true )`, not by links or entering the url yourself. To use links, you must bind a click event to them and prevent the default action and call navigate to the links href.

`router` is an instance of `Router`