# Duplicate routes called in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to have a kind of RESTful URL structure like below:

- /accounts
- /accounts/account/123

I've set up my routes as such:

```
    MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes : {
            '/accounts':                         'accounts',
            '/accounts/account/:account':        'account',
        },
        accounts: function() {
            console.log('accounts CALLED');
        },
        account: function() { 
            console.log('account CALLED');
        },
    });
```

The problem, is when I go to ***/accounts/account/123*** , both ***accounts()*** and ***account()*** get called (as the URL matches both routes). I tried a route such as ***/accounts$***, but it doesn't look like it's supported in the routes hash.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Would a manual ***router.route(route, name, callback)*** work instead  (although I really prefer not to do that).

Comment: Have you tried: `routes : {
'/accounts/account/:account':        'account',
            '/accounts':                         'accounts'
            
        },` I.E. flipping them around?

Comment: Hey there. I haven't tried that. The mapping is happening correctly [as per the docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router). I'm just curious as to why those duplicate functions are being called. When I call the router.navigate directly, however, that solves the problem. But I'm still trying to find out how to deal with browser bar and forward and back button.

Answer (score 1):

I got this cleared up by [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280322/cant-get-backbone-routes-without-hashes). I didn't realise that I had to use the ***router.navigate*** function strictly.

Using the router programmatically (not via browser bar), those duplicate calls go away. I'm also seeing the expected functions called only once... when using ***router.navigate***.

I still have to find out how to capture back & forward buttons to call those functions. Thanks for the feedback so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try /accounts$ instead.  $ is the regex for the end of the string.

Comment: I actually tried _/accounts$_ in the routes hash. But to no avail.  It works if I use the raw router function _router.route(route, name, callback)_ . It's weird, because again, all the routes are getting called. I'm just getting duplicate calls when I go to _/accounts_ , _/accounts/account/123_ , etc.