# Backbone routing pushstate unable to go to the link

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I'm new to `Backbone.js` and I'm experiencing `routes`. 
I set a `route`, and navigating it through an `input` with

```
route.navigate("stream")
```

I firstly created a `router`:

```
    app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "stream": "stream"
    }

    ,initialize: function(){
    }

    ,home: function(){
        console.log("Home");
    }
    ,stream: function(){
        console.log("Streaming");
        new app.streamView();
    }

})
```

If I use the `input` to `navigate` to `/stream`, and it works.

But, If I navigate to `www.mysite.it/stream` it shows me `404` `Error`. Any advice?

Comment: What happens if you navigate to www.mysite.it/#stream? You might be forgetting this: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})

Comment: I'm using it, if I use the `#` it works.

Comment: Maybe the browser you are working on does not support push state? Let me know if you find some helpful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310230/backbone-routes-without-hashes

Comment: @steo Have you setup the `/stream` route in your backend?

Comment: @KyleNeedham not yet. Now that I see, it make sense that is not working.