# Backbone Route not firing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

This should be super basic but I can't get routing working. I should mention that the application is located in a subdirectory called /dist/. Here's my code:

```
    var QuestionRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      "/dist/" : "startTest"
      "dist/:id": "getModel"
    },

    startTest: function(){
      console.log('home called')
    },

    getModel: function(){
        app.getModel(id);
    }

});


  var app = new QuestionView;
  var appRouter = new QuestionRouter;
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

The URL to trigger this route is:

```
    www.example.com/dist/
    www.example.com/dist/12345
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone routes without hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310230/backbone-routes-without-hashes)

Comment: @EmileBergeron How is it a duplicate? The code in question has `{pushState: true}`

Comment: @TJ It is a duplicate because OP wants to know how to use Backbone URL without hashes. He's using `pushState` but the rest is explained inside the duplicate.

Comment: @EmileBergeron not sure what extra information is there that explains why these routes in above code are  not triggered? I don't see what modification OP can do to his code to make it work based on the suggested duplicate...

Comment: @TJ when using `pushState`, it's needed to prevent the default link behaviour and call `Backbone.navigate` instead or make your backend always return the same index page, but that kills the no reload advantage of an SPA.

Comment: @TJ Yes my route is still not working even though I have pushstate enabled, or is my route not configured properly? startTest() is not being called at the path /dist/.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `#` (hash symbol).

> Backbone routers are used for routing your applications URL's when
>   using hash tags(#)

This is a quote from a Backbone tutorial: [What is a router?](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-router)

See [Backbone's Router documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Then your routes would be:

```
www.example.com/#/dist/
www.example.com/#/dist/12345
```

You can also use [Backbone routes without hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310230/backbone-routes-without-hashes).

Comment: This is not required with `{pushState: true}` option

Comment: If `pushState` is not the intended goal, this could work.

Comment: Yes, you can make use of html5 feature PushState. See the aforementioned stackoverflow entry.

From http://backbonejs.org/#History: To indicate that you'd like to use HTML5 pushState support in your application, use Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}).

Comment: I can't use /#/dist/ as the files are located in the sub directory dist. So if i try /dist/# I'm still not getting anything to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I was able to work this out:

1. My route hash should look like this:

   routes: {
     "" : "startTest",
     ":id": "getModel"
   }
2. I had to remove pushState: true, with this in place the route wasn't being triggered, not sure why:

   Backbone.history.start();